# How to drag two view synchronously？

Tags: react-native

[image: drag puzzle]

I want to move puzzle piece by dragging the sliding button.

Comment: consider to use [PanResponder]:(https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html) to handle it

Comment: Is `Animation` library needed?